# Trigger or multiple queries ? Performance efficiency?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I am designing a web application using php and mysql. I have a little doubt in database.
The application is like

1. Users get themselves registered.
2. Users input workload (after login ofcourse :) ).
3. User logs out.

Now there are multiple types of inputs which i accept on a same form. Say there are 3 types of inputs and they are stored in 7 different tables (client requirement :( )

Now my question is what is the best way to fire a query after inputs are done ?
For now i can think of following ways.

1. Fire 7 different queries from php
2. Write a trigger to propagate inputs in appropriate tables ?

Just guide me which approach is performance efficient ?
 Thanks :)

Comment: I think you mean "Stored Procedure", rather than "Trigger", since having a Trigger would mean you'd need somewhere for the data to live while the Trigger executes, and something else to clean it up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you want to stay away from triggers because you will be penalized later if you have to load a lot of data. Stored procedures are the way to go. You can have different conditions set to propagate inputs into different tables if needed.

Comment: While triggers shouldn't be overused, they do have legitimate uses.

Comment: Of course! They seem so cool when one learns about them, and then you learn not to overuse them. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to re-think your situation. You already know how awesome it would be to have fewer tables to deal with? Well, why not simulate that situation with a properly constructed view. Then, the client (are you sure it is the client? Sometimes ops says "client", when they mean, "report which we need to provide later") can have as many tables as your database can handle. And, by the way, you can still fire [inserts and updates on a view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html).

Because it seems like your database does not have a clear relationship with PHP data structures, my instinct will be to separate the two more, not less. This would mean actually favoring stored procedures and triggers (assuming the above is not workable), which can be harder to debug, but it also means that PHP only has to think about

> "I am inserting into this *thing* called <thing name>"

Instead of

> "OMG, so this is like, totally intense first I have to talk to <table 1>, but I can't forget <table 2>, especially since those two might have... wait, did I miss my turn?"

OK, PHP isn't a ditz (I actually like the language), but it also should also be acting as *dumb as possible* when it comes to actually *storing* things -- that's' not its business.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to write a stored procedure that runs the seven queries. Think hard about how many transactions you need to run those seven queries.

Answer (score 0):

How often do you think you will have to change which queries to run?

Do you have access to the database server?

Do you know which circumstance should trigger your triggers?

Are there other processes/applications writing data to the database?

If your queries change very often, I would go for code in PHP to just run the queries for you.

If you don't have access to the database server you may actually have to go for that method! You need permissions to write stored procedures and triggers.

If other processes are writing to the same database you have to discuss your requirements with the respective process owners! Otherwise data may appear/change in your database that was unwanted.

I personally tend to stay away from triggers unless they call very simple stored procedures and I'm 100% certain that nobody else is going to be bothered by the trigger!